# Nginx+Symfony2 remove app.php from url

Tags: symfony, nginx

i've added `rewrite ^/app\.php/?(.*)$ /$1 permanent;` to my config file, but it creates a redirection loop.

Any idea? First time i'm using nginx ...

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use following host config

```
server {
    listen       127.0.0.1:80;
    server_name  symfony2.dev;

    root   /Users/user/public_html/symfony/web/;
    index   app_prod.php;
    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    rewrite ^/app_prod\.php/?(.*)$ /$1 permanent;

    location / {
        root   /Users/user/public_html/symfony/web/;
        try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
    }

    location @rewriteapp {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /app_prod.php$1 last;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ ^/(app)(_\w+)?\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass        127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 8k;
        fastcgi_buffers     256 16k;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        fastcgi_param       SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param       HTTPS              off;
        include         fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }
}
```